# I cannot refresh an excel file that is connected to MS access database

Tags: ms-access-2010

I built a query in MS access 2013.
I closed the MS access app.
I linked the query in Excel.

But now, when my excel file is opened, I can see that there is a ".laccdb" opened also. It's acting like my whole MS access DB was opened. So i can't refresh my query because its giving me "You attempted to open a database that is already opened by user 'Admin' on machine 'My Computer.'  Try again when the database is available."

How can I fix that?

Comment: It's a known issue. It should be corrected if the go to Settings and force an update of Office 2013.

Comment: I dont get it, what?

Comment: Sorry, I have not this old version running, so I can't show the details.